# DestinationAccessException Error in executing ODATA V2 calls using S4 SDK in cloud foundry environment

Tags: s4sdk

The destination used for executing calls is configured for authentication type as **oAuth2SAMLBearerAssertion**, The business user is already onboard in the system with userid, email and other basic details. On calling execute method from SDK I get below error:

```
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get authentication headers. Destination service returned error: Provided authorization grant is invalid. Exception was No user found with alias 'name@domain.com' (format: unspecified). For more information, consult the kernel traces or the OAuth 2.0 troubleshooting SAP note 1688545.
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is resolved by adding following properties in configured destination:

**nameIdFormat** urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress

here nameIdFormat is the additional property name.